# How do you extract/install from an .iso file?

Tags: windows, dvd, burning, iso-image, virtual-drive

I've downloaded an .iso file but don't have a DVD writer at the moment - is there a recommended Virtual DVD drive that I can use to install from the .iso file?

Comment: What OS is this on?

Comment: @therefromhere Windows :)

Comment: Very related: [How do I place a bootable ISO on a USB drive? - Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/66948/how-do-i-place-a-bootable-iso-on-a-usb-drive) (for solutions that don't use USB see [installation - Install Windows 7 from ISO image - Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/154109/install-windows-7-from-iso-image/154112) )

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Without knowing exactly what operating system you're running, I recommend using either [VirtualCloneDrive](http://www.slysoft.com/en/virtual-clonedrive.html) or [Magic Disc](http://www.magiciso.com/tutorials/miso-magicdisc-overview.htm). Both are free and work on just about any version of Windows (including 64-bit versions). Plus they don't have the crapware that Daemon Tools tries to shove down your throat.

Answer (score 22):

[7-Zip](http://www.7-zip.org/) will open ISOs too (as well as being generally superb.)

Comment: Does it mount a partition? I cant find the option. And yes, its a superb piece of software.

Comment: You can just use "Extract To..." and extract all the contents to a folder.

Answer (score 8):

Assuming Windows, you can try [Daemon Tools](http://www.daemon-tools.cc/eng/downloads).

In Linux you can mount an ISO similarly to the way you mount other volumes:

```
mount -o loop -t iso9660 file.iso /mnt/test
```

Alternatively, if the installer doesn't mandate a "physical" volume to install from you can also extract the contents of the ISO file (archivers such as [WinRAR](http://rarsoft.com/) are usually able to do this, but there's also special software for this) and run the installer from there.

Answer (score 5):

I usually use [PowerISO](http://www.poweriso.com/download.htm).

Answer (score 2):

There are a few alternatives in this [question](https://superuser.com/questions/3804/free-windows-iso-mounting-software) providing that your are running Windows.

I'm using [MagicISO](http://www.magiciso.com/) myself and it works fine, although you have to buy a license to open ISO files larger than 300MB. An alternative is [MagicDisc](http://www.magiciso.com/tutorials/miso-magicdisc-overview.htm), a freeware virtual drive from MagicISO that can be used to mount ISO files as virtual drives.

Answer (score 2):

There is a free program called AlZip that will let you open/extract an ISO file like a regular compressed file (zip, rar, etc) It also supports these other formats, of course. [Get it here](http://www.altools.com/Downloads/ALZip.aspx)

edit: it used to be free (ad-supported) for non-commercial users, but they seem to have changed the policy recently...

Also check out all the other free utility programs this Korean company has created.
I can't remember if it was AlZip, but one of them adds a very useful "create new folder" context menu item.

Answer (score 0):

I use Total Commander plugin ISO:

http://www.totalcmd.net/plugring/iso.html

It won't open certain ISO files though.

Comment: @ondatra on what OS does it work on?

Comment: Windows (or maybe on Linux if you run Total Commander in Wine)

Answer (score 0):

7Zip will allow you to extract ISO files, it also lets you extract the boot files from a Windows XP/Vista/7/etc ISO

Answer (score -1):

There are a lots of software and tools can mount an ISO file. I've tested 2 or 3 tools and [Virtual CloneDrive](https://www.elby.ch/en/products/vcd.html) is my favorite for win XP and 7. And win 10 comes with built in ISO mount/Unmount support. I also have a tutorial about this http://pointblankpro.com/how-to-mount-an-iso-image-in-windows/

And If you are on Linux Machine, Then you can use a single line command to Mount any ISO file to your linux machine. AskUbuntu has a thread about Mounting ISO's in Ubuntu https://askubuntu.com/questions/411793/mount-iso-using-the-terminal