# How to install Windows 8 from Ubuntu without a USB or DVD?

Tags: ubuntu, installation, windows-8

Last week my windows 7 operating system crashed. So I installed Ubuntu 10.04 on the partition Windows 7 was previously on. I have two Partitions, C: and D:. In partition D: I have very important data and I can't format it (I can't backup because it's very heavy ~50 GB). Now I want to install Windows 8.

I have downloaded the ISO file of Windows 8 Pro. I don't have a DVD writer or a USB device to Install this. I need to install this on C: partition (the partition on which I have already installed Ubuntu) and I need to protect the data in partition D:. How do I do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I install Windows 8 on my HDD without the use of a USB or DVD?](http://superuser.com/questions/490476/how-can-i-install-windows-8-on-my-hdd-without-the-use-of-a-usb-or-dvd)

Comment: Currently I'm running on Ubuntu so I can't use windows methodes

Comment: Edited the title, based on the comment above this doesn't seem to be a duplicate. Edit: I can't test this, but it would be nice if someone can check whether it's *at all* possible to do this by making Grub boot from an ISO (see [1](http://superuser.com/questions/154133/grub-boot-from-iso), [2](http://superuser.com/questions/154134/grub-how-to-boot-into-iso-partition)).

Comment: Are you able to resize either partition?

Answer (score 4):

"Frugal  Install" using [UNetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/).

> UNetbootin can create a bootable Live USB drive, or **it can
>   make a "**frugal install**" on your local hard disk** if you don't have a
>   USB drive. It loads distributions either by downloading a ISO (CD
>   image) files for you, **or by using an ISO file you've already
>   downloaded.**

You would create a partition and use UNetbootin to install the ISO onto that partition (instead of burning it onto a cd/dvd). I have not tried this with Windows, but with Linux...

Answer (score -2):

I agree with UNetbutin, or however it's spelled, but i would like to say that there is other ways like Getting the ISO image and getting software to decode the image.