# How to Install Linux Mint 13 from LAN

Tags: boot, lan, linux-mint

I want to install Linux on my older system which does not have a CD-ROM and it can also not boot from USB. It can boot from Network. Is there any guide for installing Linux Mint 13 from LAN? or some tool/utility to make this thing simpler?

Can I boot from USB attached to another system on LAN?

Answer (score 1):

You would typically need to set up a BOOTP + DHCP server then boot over the network via PXE. The following link is a guide on how to do so:

http://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=197&t=96322

You might also be interested in http://www.oneclickkick.com/ which could make the process a lot easier for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can also copy the CD (as an iso image) to the old machine's hard drive and use grub2 to boot directly from it. I used to install SuSe this way a few years ago. Have a look at [this](https://superuser.com/questions/154133/grub-boot-from-iso) question for more details.