# I have Ubuntu .iso file downloaded in my Linux Mint - how to install Ubuntu OS?

Tags: ubuntu, installation, operating-systems

From my Linux Mint operating system, how do I install/dual-boot this Ubuntu OS which is downloaded as a .iso file?

So that it comes up as an option to boot into when I first turn on my computer. Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [grub: boot from ISO](http://superuser.com/questions/154133/grub-boot-from-iso)

Comment: @ЯрославРахматуллин: I think he would be happy with a "normal" CD or USB-based install procedure. Going by his question and responses below it seems he just wants to know how he can use the ISO to install Ubuntu (I doubt he's interested in messing with Grub and booting directly from the ISO itself).

Comment: So the question is "how do I burn and boot an ISO?"

Comment: @ЯрославРахматуллин: Yes, *IMO* that's all he wants to know, although of course he needs to confirm that himself.

Answer (score 3):

Linux Mint has an application for creating bootable live USBs for installing Linux distros called *Startup Disk Creator* (*usb-creator-gtk*).

The USB flash drive that you use with Startup Disk Creator should be 2GB or larger, and for Ubuntu 18.04 and later it should be 4GB or larger. Startup Disk Creator will automatically format your USB flash drive to FAT32 and make it bootable. If you have only one USB flash drive plugged in to your computer, Startup Disk Creator will select it automatically. Be **very careful** to select the USB flash drive in the Make Startup Disk window in order to avoid overwriting the partition which Mint is installed on, which may make Mint unbootable. In the screenshot below you can see how the USB flash drive Device is identified by its model name, the same model name that appears under the Drive heading after Model: in the Disks (disk utility) application.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I usually go the tried and true method: Burn to a CD and pop in drive, reboot, change the boot order in the BIOS to boot from CD FIRST, reboot a second time and install.

This may be your only option. I know Ubuntu has an app called [Wubi](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/windows-installer) that can install from within a OS but its windows specific.

So in your case, crack into a terminal

> dd if=/dev/drive of=my_distro.iso bs=2048

or you can get a copy of something like k3b or Brasero and burn through a GUI.

EDIT: Also, verify the checksum of the ISO before you burn. Will save you MANY headaches if you somehow got a bad ISO.

Comment: After I run this command and it finishes, I should be able to turn off my computer, turn it back on, and see some sort of Ubuntu boot option?

Comment: If your BIOS is set to boot from the CD, yes - the installer will begin to load files etc and take you through the installation process. If you have MINT on the system I imagine your BIOS is already configured correctly. If not you will need to verify this and change the order if necessary

Comment: OK great - I'll post how it goes.

Comment: Dumb question - /dev/drive doesn't exist, I assume `drive` is one of those fill-in-the-blank things I should know?

Comment: What is the dd command supposed to do? Kill the iso?

Comment: dd can't burn images. cdr tools (maybe dvdr+tools or woodim ..whatever it's called these days) has a dd_something binary. They are quite different.

Comment: Dd works just fine. I've used it to make bootable iso's for a long time. Maybe you got the source and destinations in the command reversed and wiped your iso. It happens.

Comment: dd if=/dev/drive of=my_distro.iso bs=2048. "if" is input file, /dev/drive, which is not exist. "of" is output file, why is it iso? My advice, for newbies, don't use dd aka data destroyer, if You don't know how it works, never copy paste commands like above from Internet, use GUI tool.