# Stuck on GRUB command prompt after regular kernel update

Tags: linux, boot, debian, grub, kernel

I am running Debian Wheezy. Update Manager suggest to install kernel update. After update, I reboot system but instead of listing all the kernels (bootloader), it gave me a GRUB command prompt:

```
grub>
```

What should I do? Thanks in advance for any pointers.

P.S. Maybe it will be useful:

```
grub> ls
(hd0) (hd0,gpt3) (hd0,gpt2) (hd0,gpt1) (hd1)
```

**My solution**

Boot with Live CD. Open terminal and mount root partition (double check if you mount the right partition):

```
mount /dev/sda1 /mnt
```

Also mount:

```
mount -o bind /dev /mnt/dev
mount -o bind /sys /mnt/sys
mount  -t proc /proc /mnt/proc
```

(Check if you mount the right partition: Open nautilus and navigate to `/mnt`).

Execute:

```
chroot /mnt
```

And finally run:

```
update-grub
```

Exit (`exit`) from the terminal and reboot.

Comment: It seems that `update-grub` did not run properly after the new kernel files were installed. I suggest you boot a Live CD and run `update-grub` from there.

Comment: 1.) Can I use Ubuntu's Live CD? 2.) Open terminal in Live CD and enter `grub-update`?

Comment: Yes, Ubuntu is Debian-based.

Comment: Booted with Debian Live CD, open terminal, execute `update-grub` but `command not found`.

Comment: **update-grub** is a shell script containing `grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg`. Does this work?

Comment: @AFH Same, can't find `grub-mkconfig`.

Comment: They should be on your hard disc. If not use synaptic to install them (temporarily) in your Live CD.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need a live CD to solve this.

Type:

```
grub> ls
```

Here you should see a list of devices/partitions. Now we must find the partition that contains "/boot"

```
grub> ls (hd0,gpt1)/
```

The slash at the end is necessary. You may see "msdos" instead of "gpt". If this is the right partition we should see:

> boot etc root bin ...

Type:

```
grub> set root=(hd0,gpt1)

grub> linux /boot/vmlinuz...(Press tab and choose the last working version) root=/dev/sda1

grub> initrd /boot/init...(press tab and select the same version as above)

grub> boot
```

This is just an example, you should modify it accordingly.

Comment: Glad it helped.

Comment: How to make it boot not in blind mode?