# gParted > FAT32 formatted USB is not recognized in Windows 10

Tags: gparted

I've tried several times now. I format a 120GB USB3.0 drive as FAT32 using gParted in Ubuntu(from a live USB) then when I try and mount in Windows 10 it doesn't mount. I then open Disk Management and have no option but to reformat the RAW partition as ExFat.

What could cause the gParted FAT32 parition to not be recognized in Win10?

Comment: My guess; MS left out the driver, "to help you" use the right disk format. I jumped to use Linux to get rid of this kind of idiosyncrasies.

Comment: On unix.SE: [gparted - Windows doesn't like resized FAT filesystem - Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/333634/windows-doesnt-like-resized-fat-filesystem)

Comment: Review my answer to https://superuser.com/questions/1500817/why-windows-doesnt-recognize-a-fat32-external-drive there might be some hints.

Answer (score 2):

There is a bug in some versions of libparted that fails to preserve the file system boot sector code when **resizing** a FAT32 partition.  I *assume* that you may have resized the FAT32 partition.

See [Bug 759916 - fat(32) resizing generates boot sector(s) with invalid jump instruction and pseudo-random boot code](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=759916)

For Windows to recognize FAT32, it needs the initial bytes (at least 3 bytes "eb 58 90") set as follows:

```
$ sudo hexdump -n 7k -C /dev/sda1
00000000  eb 58 90 4d 53 57 49                              |.X.MSWI|
00000007
```

To work around this issue after it has occurred, use a hexeditor such as hexedit to set the initial 3 bytes of the FAT32 file system at the start of the partition.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, but in my disk management it is FAT32, but not accessible. try to add drive letter in "Change drive letter and path.." when you right click to it, and it works like a charm