# ISO file installation

Tags: windows, iso-image

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you extract/install from an .iso file?](https://superuser.com/questions/17309/how-do-you-extract-install-from-an-iso-file)

Is there any way I could install the software (in ISO format) on my computer without burning it on DVD/CD?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like [Daemon Tools](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daemon_Tools) allows you to mount an ISO as if it were in a DVD drive.  The lite version is, I believe, free.